# What is the correct way to get an NDR to be sent when a bounce back occurs?

Tags: smtp, ndr, return-path

I have a user who developed a WebApp that sends SMTP messages.  Users are able to reply to the message using a MUA (outlook, whatever) but there is no NDR if the user doesn't exist.

I suspect that the envelope is empty or missing and only the body is populated with a From.

Since I doubt their ability to fix the problem correctly, I want to offer them suggestions on how to fix this.

Is it correct for me to suggest any of the following (mutually exclusive of each other)

1. To Set the FROM address in the envelope, and not just the body
2. Ask them to set the header Return-Path:asdf@company.com
3. ???

Answer (score 1):

`Return-Path` header contains COPY of envelope sender email address (email used in `MAIL FROM:` command in SMTP session).  It may be overwritten by mail servers.

Ask them to set envelope sender address. Most likely currently it is set to mailbox they do not monitor (e.g. www-data).

BTW you may use [VERP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VERP) to simplify bounces processing.